# How to get ResourcesTree node from schedulerstorage resource datasource in Devexpress Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a requirement where in based on some text in resource tree , i should highlight the corresponding row. I know we can get it done by **resourcesTree.FindNodeByID(1).Selected = true;**
But how to get the node id from datasource, since i am assigning a custom resource for the schedulerstorage datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the node by using [`TreeListNode.FindNodeByFieldValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FindNodeByFieldValuetopic) method:

```
resourcesTree.FindNodeByFieldValue("SomeColumnName", "SomeText").Selected = true;
```

Also, you can use the [`TreeList.FindNode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FindNodetopic) method:

```
resourcesTree.FindNode(node =>
{
    var item = (YourSchedulerStorageItem)resourcesTree.GetDataRecordByNode(node);
    return item.SomeProperty == "SomeText";
}).Selected = true;
```

---

But also you can highlight the tree list rows by using search engine. For this you can use [`TreeList.ApplyFindFilter`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_ApplyFindFiltertopic) method.
For example, if you have this tree:
[image: Tree list]
Then you can use this:

```
treeList.ApplyFindFilter("\"Task 1\"");
```

And all `Task 1` nodes will be highlighted:
[image: Highlighted tree list]